# Using SubSonic, how to add a field to a pre-defined class?

Tags: subsonic, object, arraylist, serialization

I've got a SubSonic DAL - works great.

Two classes:  TblReceipt and TblReceiptLineItems.

I can create a parallel class of TblReceipt, but seems like a waste, so here's what I need to do:

Have a Class TblReceipt with one additional member, "ReceiptLineItems" - which is simply an ArrayList.  This array list will be populated with TblReceiptLineItems types.

So for each Receipt, there are 1..* ReceiptLineItems stored in the array, then the whole thing is serialized.

How can I accomplish this with my existing SubSonic DAL?

A quick code sample would be useful too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a partial class. All classes in Subsonic are defined as partial. What you do is (in a separate file than the one that is generated by Subsonic), you create another part of the partial class with the additional property.

Option 2 here:
[http://jamesewelch.wordpress.com/2008/09/24/how-to-use-custom-audit-fields-with-subsonic/](http://jamesewelch.com/2008/09/24/how-to-use-custom-audit-fields-with-subsonic/)